# Pi won't boot without USB drive inserted

Tags: pi-2, pi-3, fstab

I want my Pi to mount my USB drive at boot if the drive is inserted, however, I also want the Pi to boot regardless of whether or not the drive is inserted at startup or not.  I edited my `fstab` file and used my devices UUID to mount it, and it works fine, but like the title says, it won't boot without the drive inserted.

I read online that I need to write `nofail` in my `fstab` line, which I tried doing but I think I did it wrong as it still won't boot.  Here is the line I have written in my `fstab` file:

```
UUID=9687-3A59 /mnt/usb vfat defaults 0 2, nofail
```

Also, I read from another user on here that if you go this route by adding `nofail` to `fstab`, if the drive isn't inserted you have to wait 90 seconds for the Pi to try mounting it. Is there an alternative to this? Something where I won't have to wait if it's not there, but it will still boot with or without the drive?

I am new to the Pi/Linux/Unix world, and this has all been a major learning process that I am enjoying so far.

Comment: First of all, you should add `nofail` to fstab after defaults, without a space between the comma and `fstab`. The line should look like this: `UUID=9687-3A59 /mnt/usb vfat defaults,nofail 0 2`

Comment: See `man fstab` for a better understanding of how the file should be structured.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `nobootwait` to the options section. The line should look like this:

```
UUID=9687-3A59 /mnt/usb vfat defaults,nofail,nobootwait 0 2
```